# Sweave and R 3.1.0: no pdfs generated

Tags: pdf, r, sweave

After upgrading R to version 3.1.0 (from some version 2.x.x), the following sweave code does not produce any pdfs for the plots anymore:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\SweaveOpts{echo=FALSE}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
<<fig = T, echo = F, include=T>>=
x=rnorm(100)
plot(x)
@
\caption{My Graph}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

To compile, I use `R CMD Sweave foo.Rnw` followed by `R CMD pdflatex foo.tex`. Why is that and how can I fix it? I played around with the options: `fig = TRUE`, `pdf = TRUE` and so on - to no avail.

Edit: Here is the output of `R CMD Sweave foo.Rnw`, which should create the pdf files:

```
R CMD Sweave foo.Rnw
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
Output file:  foo.tex
R CMD pdflatex foo.tex
....
```

Comment: Did you re-install `ggplot2` for R version 3?

Comment: Your example works for me after upgrading to the latest R - but *only* after I had re-installed `ggplot2` and all of its dependencies.

Comment: @Thruston: sorry, the ggplot library is actually not needed. Even when using the standard plot-function, no pdfs are generated.

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: No. I'll add the output of the first command to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated R to version 3.1.1 (by removing R 3.1.0 and installing R 3.1.1 from source) - and voila, it works!